# show sequence converges

Tags: analysis, limits

If $(x_n)$ and $(y_n)$ are Cauchy sequences in a metric space X with metric d, how would I show the sequence $(d(x_n,y_n))$ converges?

I'm supposed to use  $d(x_n,y_n)\leq d(x_n,x_m)+d(x_m,y_m)+d(y_m,y_n)$
If I subtract by $d(x_m,y_m)$ on both sides:

$d(x_n,y_n)-d(x_m,y_m)\leq d(x_n,x_m)+d(y_m,y_n)$

Since $d(x_n,x_m)$ and $d(y_m,y_n)$ are Cauchy, then each can be less than $\frac{\epsilon}{2}$ which makes the left side $\leq \epsilon$. How would I show it converges though?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT: Show that $\langle d(x_n,y_n):n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ is a Cauchy sequence in $\Bbb R$, and use the fact that $\Bbb R$ is complete: every Cauchy sequence in $\Bbb R$ converges.

Comment: Thanks, how would show it's a Cauchy sequence in R particularly, though?

Comment: @Alti: By showing that it satisfies the definition of a Cauchy sequence: for each $\epsilon>0$ there is an $n_0\in\Bbb N$ such that $|d(x_m,y_m)-d(x_n,y_n)|<\epsilon$ whenever $m,n\ge n_0$. You’ve already done much of the work.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

The triangle inequality gives
$$
-d(y_n,y_m)\le d(x_n,y_n)-d(x_n,y_m)\le d(y_n,y_m)
$$
and
$$
-d(x_n,x_m)\le d(x_m,y_m)-d(x_n,y_m)\le d(x_n,x_m)
$$
Subtracting yields
$$
|d(x_n,y_n)-d(x_m,y_m)|\le d(x_n,x_m)+d(y_n,y_m)
$$